# how do I force gitlab to update submodule references?

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules

I have a super-project in a gitlab repository.  For testing purposes I originally pointed the submodules at URLs for forks in my personal space using full URLs (this was pre 8.12).

I am now on 8.14* and have changed the submodule URLs to use relative URLs into the authoritative repositories.  `git submodule sync` has worked its magic in my clone, and I've pushed into gitlab.  I can see that `.gitmodules` contains the relative URLs I desire.

HOWEVER

When I navigate the repository through the web browser to the directory containing my submodules, the links on the web page still go to projects in my personal space rather than using the canonical, relative URLs.

How do I convince gitlab to update its view?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  gitlab parses `.gitmodules` and does so rather stupidly.

In my `.gitmodules`, I had simply commented out my original URLs and *added* a new URL.  So, an entry in the file looked like this:

```
[submodule "component/subproj"]
    path = components/subproj
    url = ../subproj.git
    #url = ../../mypersonalspace/subproj.git
```

gitlab's UI was seeing the second, commented-out, `url=` and rendering that.